# How to write a pointcut for all methods of class annotated by @Service and having return type void

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I am trying to write a point cut for all void methods of classes that are annotated by @Service.

At first I tried to create two separate point cuts and then join them on advice calls but even that didnt work as I think I do not know the right format of the void method point cut declaration.

I had the following:

```
@Pointcut("execution(void * *(..))")
    public void voidMethodPointcut() {}
```

But this throws malformed pointcut expression Exception.

I am new to Spring and would really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

For methods annotated by @Service your pointcut expression should look like this:

```
execution(@your.package.name.Service void *.*(..))
```

And for all methods of classes annotated by @Service - like this:

```
execution(void (@your.package.name.Service *).*(..))
```

Comment: Its not the methods that are annotated. Its the classes.

Comment: I gave you both, because it wasn't clear from your description. So, you can use second expression

Comment: Aah my bad. Thanks, let me try this out.

Comment: I think this variant is a little more expressive and readable: `execution(void * *(..)) && @target(@your.package.name.Service)`

Comment: How does this reference @Service? This references classes named "Service" no? These examples aren't working for me.

Comment: @krigaex your version gives me the error "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference." (it doesn't like the `&& @target ...`)